# Multiline custom checkbox - force lines to indent after ::before element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I made a custom checkbox which is used like this:

with basically this styling (some more for the check functionality)

```css
input[type="checkbox"] ~ label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;3
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  top: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="someId" v-model="someValue" name="someName" class="customCheckbox"/>
<label for="someId" tabindex="-1" class="customCheckboxLabel">{{somedata}}</label>
```

now all lines after the first one start where the ::before element starts but I want them to be indent just like the first line (like in the picture below)

[image]

Is this even possible ::before or do I need seperate elements to do this?